# File upload in gwt

Tags: gwt, file-upload

I am using FileUpload control in gwt, I want to do the following things with it

1. I want to change the text displayed in the button which is displayed as "Browse" by default.
2. I want to trace the event when the I browse the file and click on open in the browsing window.
3. I want to filter the extensions and allow only .xls and .xlsx files.

Please tell me what are the ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You generally can't change the appearance of a file input selector, but you can use some [CSS tricks to disguise it](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html).  Supposedly, an `<input type="file"/>` element should support an `accept` property whose value is a MIME type for the desired type of input file, but that [isn't implemented](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_accept.asp).